# What is the recommended object format for exporting to substance painter 2?

Tags: texturing

Which object format would people recommend as the best/most effective format for exporting models to Substance Painter. I have tried .fbx and .obj and they both work slightly differently on the same model so I am seeking clarity as to the most reliable option. I am using Cycles as the renderer and the pbr-spec-gloss workflow.

Many thanks
Steve

Answer (score 1):

From experience it's highly recommended to use .Fbx formats due to it being the standard for Autodesk software. It's also natively supported in a majority of game engines as well as third party software such as those developed by algorithmic.

Comment: Hi, about FBX. Blender has its support, and Painter works with it just fine. The problem rising when this FBX imported into Unreal Engine 4. It looks just broken. Tried different export options with no luck (even triangulated model before export) - Painter bakes normal map just perfect, but UE4 cannot interpret it like Painter.

Answer (score 1):

If you absolutely, positively, surely need it to work in SP2, export it as an .obj, tweak the modifiers and options as needed, and it is guaranteed to work.  You can try .fbx, and it will likely work as well, but if you have anything else going on (such as animations or shapes) then things get a little more iffy.

SP2 can also allegedly take .blend files raw, but I suspect it is pulling a Unity3d behind the scenes, and will use Blender commandline to convert it to an .fbx first.  You are likely better off doing that manually instead.